# Destroy objects in real life (Compositing)

Tags: compositing-nodes

How can I use Blender Compositing, to do a fracture cube, and compositing it into a video, for example where are building or something is destroy itself.. :)

But the texture of the building in the Video should be match with the destroying cube, so it should be look like it was real happening.. :)

I hope you understand what I mean... :)

When you not understand it, then watch this video from the minute 1:10.15, where he is "match" the texture with the ground break... :) 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2R7N8UqT04U&list=RD2R7N8UqT04U&start_radio=1

So I hope anybody can help me? :)

Thanks for answers :D

Comment: In fact its NOT clear what You wanna do, Daniel. I saw the video and the only thing texture-related is the plane of the road. You want to texture the cube like the road is or what exactly? Cause if You only need the breaking object to "as if" cast shadows on the real-life footage then "Shadow Catcher" plane is your thing.

Comment: yes I want to texturing the cube like the road :)

Comment: If U have already some progress please post here your .blend file. So to break things out ... U want the cube look like the road, the cube cast the shadow on the road or both? No matter what Yo answer is without the scene its complicated and in fact if U want to texture an object to look like something in the "real" footage/photo U simply have to make the texture/material which is sometimes a real pain. But if U send the scene I will take a look bro ;). Use this (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Sorry, my englisch is not so good to explain things in englisch... :)

Comment: I will send you the file :) I would like to make a ground break like during an earthquake :)

Comment: but you need to download this http://graphicall.org/1148
because with this "addon" you can make things to fracture ;)

Comment: here is the file... I have upload it on mediafire... :) if you doesnt see the video in side blender, so I have upload it on mediafire too... so you can download it and after that you can try what I say :D
https://www.mediafire.com/folder/q4gc112p4wqzr/ here :D

Comment: Hi, I have the file but ... do You using Blender render or Cycles?

Comment: Cycles  render engine

Comment: ...and U have NO textures in the .blend?

Comment: yes.. only the video

Comment: So ... Ive got Yo scene working somehow but.. The way U wanna do the "trick" is NOT the way U have to do it! This video will help FOR SURE ;). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY